# I need a way to compare two strings in python without using sets in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on a huge csv file with pandas, and I need to find and print similarity between the selected row and every other row. For example if the string is "Card" and the second string is "Credit Card Debit Card" it should return 2 or if the first string is "Credit Card" and the second string is "Credit Card Debit Card" it should return 3 because 3 of the words match with the first string. I tried solving this using sets but because of sets being unique and not containing duplicates in the first example instead of 2 it returns 1. Because in a set "Credit Card Debit Card" is {"Credit", "Card", "Debit"}. Is there anyway that I can calculate this? The formula of similarity is ((numberOfSameWords)/whichStringisLonger)*100 as explained in this photo:

[image]

I tried so many things like Jaccard Similarity but they all work with sets and return wrong answers. Thanks for any help.
The code I tried running:

```
def test(row1, row2):
    return str(round(len(np.intersect1d(row1.split(), row2.split())) / max(len(row1.split()), len(row2.split()))*100, 2))

data = int(input("Which index should be tested:"))
for j in range(0,10):
    print(test(dff['Product'].iloc[data], dff['Product'].iloc[j]))
```

and my dataframe currently looks like this:

[image]

`print(df.sample(10).to_dict("list"))` returned me:

```
{'Product': ['Bank account or service', 'Credit card', 'Credit reporting', 'Credit reporting credit repair services or other personal consumer reports', 'Credit reporting', 'Mortgage', 'Debt collection', 'Mortgage', 'Mortgage', 'Credit reporting'], 'Issue': ['Deposits and withdrawals', 'Billing disputes', 'Incorrect information on credit report', "Problem with a credit reporting company's investigation into an existing problem", 'Incorrect information on credit report', 'Applying for a mortgage or refinancing an existing mortgage', 'Disclosure verification of debt', 'Loan servicing payments escrow account', 'Loan servicing payments escrow account', 'Incorrect information on credit report'], 'Company': ['CITIBANK NA', 'FIRST NATIONAL BANK OF OMAHA', 'EQUIFAX INC', 'Experian Information Solutions Inc', 'Experian Information Solutions Inc', 'BANK OF AMERICA NATIONAL ASSOCIATION', 'AllianceOne Recievables Management', 'SELECT PORTFOLIO SERVICING INC', 'OCWEN LOAN SERVICING LLC', 'Experian Information Solutions Inc'], 'State': ['CA', 'WA', 'FL', 'UT', 'MI', 'CA', 'WA', 'IL', 'TX', 'CA'], 'ZIP_code': ['92606', '98272', '329XX', '84321', '486XX', '94537', '984XX', '60473', '76247', '91401'], 'Complaint_ID': [90452, 2334443, 1347696, 2914771, 1788024, 2871939, 1236424, 1619712, 2421373, 1803691]}
```

Comment: You might try using `collections.Counter`, which could give you a dictionary of counts for each list of strings.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Tried using that but it didn't really give me a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = ["Debt collection", "Debt collection", "Managing loan lease", "Managing loan lease",
      "Credit reporting credit repair services personal consumer reports", "Credit reporting credit repair services personal consumer report"]
l2 = ["Debt collection", "Mortgage", "Problems end loan lease", "Struggling pay loan",
      "Payday loan title loan personal loan", "Credit card prepaid card"]

df = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns=["col1"])
df["col2"] = l2


def similarity(row1, row2):
    # calculate longest row
    longestSentence = 0
    commonWords = 0
    wordsRow1 = [x.upper() for x in row1.split()]
    wordsRow2 = [x.upper() for x in row2.split()]
    # calculate similar words in both sentences
    common = list(set(wordsRow1).intersection(wordsRow2))
    if len(wordsRow1) > len(wordsRow2):
        longestSentence = len(wordsRow1)
        commonWords = calculate(common, wordsRow1)
    else:
        longestSentence = len(wordsRow2)
        commonWords = calculate(common, wordsRow2)
    return (commonWords / longestSentence) * 100

def calculate(common, longestRow):
    sum = 0
    for word in common:
        sum += longestRow.count(word)
    return sum

df['similarity'] = df.apply(lambda x: similarity(x.col1, x.col2), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how can I make this to work with multithreading? I need to make this an IO task for it to work with threads I think I am not so sure tho. Sorry for disturbing you again.

Comment: multithread also depends on how many cores your machine have. pandas is a library that can handle big amount of data, but in cases the data you need to handle is really big, you can try other libraries (you will need to google it). As far as I know they might even have the same syntax.

Comment: This is for a project and the project requires me to use multithreading. But for it to work I think I need to change this function to be I/O bound which I have no idea how to.

Comment: It we become I/O bound when the file will be large enough to require swapping to disk. It you have enough RAM memory, you will not benefit from multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`numpy.intersect1d`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) to get the common words but the `%` is different for the third row.

```
import numpy as np

df["Similarity_%"] = (
                        df.apply(lambda x: "%" + str(round(len(np.intersect1d(x['Col1'].split(), x['Col2'].split()))
                                                          / max(len(x["Col1"].split()), len(x["Col2"].split()))
                                                          *100, 2)), axis=1)
                     )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
                                                                Col1                                  Col2 Similarity_%
0                                                    Debt collection                       Debt collection       %100.0
1                                                    Debt collection                              Mortgage         %0.0
2                                                Managing loan lease               Problems end loan lease        %50.0
3                                                Managing loan lease                   Struggling pay loan       %33.33
4  Credit reporting credit repair services personal consumer reports  Payday loan title loan personal loan        %12.5
```

##### # Input used:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['Debt collection', 'Debt collection', 'Managing loan lease', 'Managing loan lease', 
                           'Credit reporting credit repair services personal consumer reports'],
                  'Col2': ['Debt collection', 'Mortgage', 'Problems end loan lease', 'Struggling pay loan',
                           'Payday loan title loan personal loan']})
```

##### # Update:

Based on the second given dataframe in your question, you can use a cross join (with [**`pandas.DataFrame.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)) to compare each row of the column `Product` to the rest of the rows of the same colum.

Try this :

```
out = df[["Product"]].merge(df[["Product"]], how="cross", suffixes=("", "_cross"))

out["Similarity_%"] = (
                        out.apply(lambda x: "%" + str(round(len(np.intersect1d(x['Product'].split(), x['Product_cross'].split()))
                                                          / max(len(x["Product"].split()), len(x["Product_cross"].split()))
                                                          *100, 2)), axis=1)
                     )
```

With a dataframe/colum of 10 rows, the result will have 100 rows plus a similarity column.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, but you underestimated one thing. My file isn't consisted of just 10 rows it is 1.16m rows. So when I try to run your code it just gives me Unable to allocate 9.91TiB for an array. Your code runs fantastic on the first answer you provided and I just need that in a function because later I am gonna use that function to do this operation with threads. Thank you so much and sorry if I wasted your time for nothing.

Comment: No worries my friend ;). Hopefully someone here on SO will give you a better/performant solution.

Comment: I hope I am not asking too much when I ask of if you can check if I turned your first code into a function correctly?The def test(row1, row2) is my attempt

Comment: Yes, I run it and it gives the correct similarities between the chosen index/row and the rest of the rows. If you want a non sensitive comparison, you need to add `.lower()` before each `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
def countCommonWords( string1, string2):
  words1 = string1.lower().split()
  words2 = string2.lower().split()
  n = 0
  for word1 in words1:
    if word1 in words2: n+=1
  return n
```

Please note that:
countCommonWords( 'a b c a', 'c b a') will return 3,
but:
countCommonWords( 'c b a', 'a b c a') will return 4 and may be your solution.
We do not know if your search string may contain doubled words